# how to set multiple values for query params in vue-router's router-link

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

Using `vue-router`'s `<router-link>`, I want to redirect a user to a path like so `/projects/7363994/posts?t=apples+oranges&s=all`.

Where `t` means topics, and `s` means sources (facebook, twitter, forums etc).

ie for project 7363994, look for posts whose topics includes `apples` and `oranges` and from `all` sources.

such that, on page load for `/projects/:id/posts` endpoint, the component will first check for those params and make queries to an API for data according to those param values.

this is what I have tried:

```
<router-link 
    :to='{
        path: `posts`, 
        query: { 
            t: "apple+orange",
            s: `all`
        }
    }'
    append
>
</router-link>
```

which gives me `/projects/7363994/posts?t=apples%2Boranges&s=all`.

i was expecting the link to show up as:
`/projects/7363994/posts?t=apples+oranges&s=all`

but instead, it is showing:
`/projects/7363994/posts?t=apples%2Boranges&s=all`

notice that the `+` symbol has been replaced with `%2B`

why is that so? am I supposed to do some escaping?

---

also tried this:

```
<router-link 
    :to='{
        path: `posts`, 
        query: { 
            t: ["apple", "orange"],
            s: `all`
        }
    }'
    append
>
</router-link>
```

gives me `/projects/7363994/posts?t=apples&t=oranges&s=all`

---

I tried escaping the `+` symbol, but that doesn't seem to work as well.

anyone knows how this works? does `vue-router` even allow this to begin with?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The url is encoded so on the server side you have to decode the url for its working

When setting the value use

`decodeURIComponent(t)`

this will make the coded url to decode one

Comment: Backend change is required